# How to convert a string '010101010' into a real binary string, in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ipv6, ipv4

I want to store IP addresses into MySQL `VARBINARY(16)`. I've got the binary address as a string `'01001010010100101001010010100101'`.

When I insert it into MySQL. I realize this will not be converted automatically.

After searching PHP manual, I'm surprised that there is no function for this.

Need your help on how to convert the binary string to `VARBINARY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks you all! But I think I've found a better solution: someone posted at PHP manual page 6 years ago:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php#93085

```
<?php
function bin2bstr($input)
// Convert a binary expression (e.g., "100111") into a binary-string
{
  if (!is_string($input)) return null; // Sanity check

  // Pack into a string
  return pack('H*', base_convert($input, 2, 16));
}

function bstr2bin($input)
// Binary representation of a binary-string
{
  if (!is_string($input)) return null; // Sanity check

  // Unpack as a hexadecimal string
  $value = unpack('H*', $input);

  // Output binary representation
  return base_convert($value[1], 16, 2);
}

// Returns string(3) "ABC"
var_dump(bin2bstr('01000001 01000010 01000011'));

// Returns string(24) "010000010100001001000011"
var_dump(bstr2bin('ABC'));
?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Content is copied from original URL.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use `bindec` and `long2ip` to convert binary string to IPv4 address:

[bindec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php) - Returns the decimal equivalent of the binary number represented by the binary_string argument.

[long2ip](http://php.net/manual/en/function.long2ip.php) - Converts an long integer address into a string in (IPv4) Internet standard dotted format

```
$ip_as_int = bindec('01001010010100101001010010100101');
$ipv4 = long2ip ( $ip_as_int );
echo $ipv4;

74.82.148.165
```

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this by combining funtions `inet_ntoa` and `conv`.

```
mysql> select inet_ntoa(conv('01001010010100101001010010100101',2,10));
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| inet_ntoa(conv('01001010010100101001010010100101',2,10)) |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| 74.82.148.165                                            |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

More over, the string result can be converted to `BINARY`:

```
mysql> select CAST(inet_ntoa(conv('01001010010100101001010010100101',2,10)) AS BINARY);
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| CAST(inet_ntoa(conv('01001010010100101001010010100101',2,10)) AS BINARY) |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 74.82.148.165                                                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Also this `BINARY` string can be easily put into `VARBINARY(16)` column using a `UPDATE` or `INSERT`.

Comment: is the result the binary representation of the IP address? is the result a varbinary value?